# For complex subspace $S$, there are vectors $u,w ∈ S$ such that $u\neq zw,\ \forall z\in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, intersection-theory

The official question reads:

> Suppose U and W are each 5-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{C}^8$.
> Prove that there are two vectors  $u,w ∈ U∩W$ $\hspace{1mm}$  s.t. $\hspace{1mm}$  $u≠zw$  $\hspace{1mm}$  ∀ z ∈ $\mathbb{C}$

First I considered one subspace being in $\mathbb{R}^5$ and the other in $\mathbb{C}^5$, but I don't think that would even work here because it's asking for a generalized proof given two subspaces of $\mathbb{C}^8$.

But here's where I'm really stuck. The intersection of two subspaces is itself a subspace, right?
So then the three subspace properties hold (Additive Identity, Closure under Addition, Closure under Scalar Multiplication).

Since the question reads **for any** z ∈ $\mathbb{C}$, I'm thinking well if we let $z=a+bi$, then it's possible that $b=0$, at which point all we're dealing with is *scalar multiplication*, $\hspace{1mm}$ i.e. $\hspace{1mm}$ $u=aw$ $\hspace{2mm} ∀ a ∈ \mathbb{R}$. 
But this is totally allowed since we're working within a subspace.

Perhaps I need $u$ & $w$ to both be linearly independent, which would mean I should look at the bases of $U$ and $W$? But then what would the intersection look like? Thank you for taking the time to assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right with your second line of inquiry. Indeed, linear independence implies this condition (certainly if $u = zw$, then $u - zw = 0$ is a non-trivial linear combination of $u$ and $w$ that produces the zero vector). So, it suffices to show that $\dim(U \cap W) \ge 2$; if this is true, we can simply take the first two vectors of the basis to get two linearly independent vectors $u$ and $w$.

Now, the key result here is to use the following formula:
$$\dim(U) + \dim(V) - \dim(U \cap V) = \dim(U + V).$$
Note that $U + V$ is a subspace of $\Bbb{C}^8$, and hence has dimension at most $8$. Also, $\dim(U) + \dim(V) = 5 + 5 = 10$ by assumption. Thus
$$\dim(U \cap V) = 10 - \dim(U + V) \ge 10 - 8 = 2,$$
as required.

Comment: Ah of course!! As long as dim(U∩W)≥2, then its basis contains at least 2 linearly independent vectors and thus they cannot be scalar multiples of each other! Man I was stuck on that problem for hours! Thank you!